# Closing a window opened by `open` on the command line

Tags: javascript, macos, google-chrome

I'm trying to initiate a web-based authentication flow from a command line application. Is there a way to close a browser window that was opened by the macOS command line `open` command  (eg. not `window.open` in JavaScript) ?

If I do

```
$ open https://www.example.net/mypage/
```

and this page executes `window.close()` I'd get the following error from Chrome:

"Scripts may close only the windows that were opened by it."

(Apparently window.close only works for windows I opened using window.open)

Comment: try this `osascript -e 'quit app "<app name>"' ` 
ex:- `osascript -e 'quit app "safari"' `

Comment: It's a security feature. You'll need an external program to hack the browser.

Comment: Definitely don’t quit the entire app, that would be really annoying to anyone who already had it open. If you can find a reliable way to close the tab that’s ideal, but if not I’d recommend just redirecting to a “you can now close this tab” page.

Comment: @pavankumar Using command line `open https://some.url/path/file` opens whatever the user has set as their default browner, and may just open a new tab in an already-running instance of that browser. You can't count on it being Safari or anything in particular and, as Ry says, you definitely don't want to quit the whole app.

Comment: Anecdotally, the apps I've used that defer to web-based authentication don't close their window, they just say "you can close this window now".

Comment: @Stephen I was giving an example, to relate with cmd that I had written with `appname` just before that.